# What gradient am I missing?

Tags: css, lint

csslint.net is giving me this error:

> Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Old Webkit (Safari 4+,
>   Chrome), Opera 11.1+.

```
.ui-dialog, .grey_box {
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
}
```

Comment: You are aware that the only "major" browser that currently requires prefixing for gradients is UC Browser, right? Most other browsers haven't required prefixing for a while now and IE never required prefixing. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these two additional

```
.ui-dialog, .grey_box {
  background:  -webkit-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
  background:  -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the unprefixed version.